# Could not load source 'dart:core/date_time.dart': <source not available>

Tags: dart, flutter

I got this error while parsing DateTime. Here is my code.

```
expDeliveryDate = DateTime.parse(json["ExpDeliveryDate"])
```

The error i got is,

```
Could not load source 'dart:core/date_time.dart': <source not available>.
```

from this file

```
date_time.dart
```

Comment: Do you have a line like `import 'dart:core/date_time.dart';` in your code? What SDK version are you on? Can you post full repro instructions?

Comment: Same problem here.
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

Answer (score 0):

When importing files, try not to use `_...` instead [always_use_package_imports](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#always_use_package_imports).

Example:

Add `date_time` to dependencies like:

```
dependencies:
  date_time: ^0.4.4
```

and then `run flutter packages get` and import it like

```
import 'package:date_time/date_time.dart';
```

Another thing to try is check if [Flutter installation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted) is okay. See also [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24912), it might be related to your issue.